# I need to print the line number along with the content prompting from user, How to do that? I tried this following code but it doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Even if the line number is more than the present content it has to display the line numbers for empty lines and then print the user input in the specified line number with the content.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    file2='file2.txt'
    echo -en "Enter the line number:"
    read line_number
    echo -en "Enter the name of the city:"
    read city_name 
    total= 0
    if [ "$line_number" > "$total" ]
    then
       awk -v  city_name="$city_name" -v line_no="$line_no" -F, {print 
       city_name} 1' "file2"
    fi
```

Comment: _display_ - how? _print_ - whereto?

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I suggest to replace `>` with `-gt`.

Comment: What are the contents of `file2`? I think it's better if you tell us step by step on what you're trying to accomplish e.g. `1) ... 2) ... 3) ...` so on and so forth.

Comment: Sure man. The content of the file contains just 7 strings line by line.                                    Delhi
DUMDUM
Dehradun
Trichy
Cochin
DERABASI
Chennai.                                                                                                                           With which I'm trying to add a user input along with the line number prompting from user. If the line no is 52 and the string is punjab I'm expecting it to print on the line leaving all the rest of the lines numbered with blank

Answer (score 0):

Use `-lt/-gt` instead of '</>'

```
>>> x=7
>>> y=99
>>> if [ $x < $y ] ; then echo "x < y"; else echo "x >= y" ; fi
x >= y

>>> if [[ $x -lt $y ]] ; then echo "x < y"; else echo "x >= y" ; fi
x < y
```

Or use double `[[]]`

```
>>> if [[ $x < $y ]] ; then echo "x < y"; else echo "x >= y" ; fi
x < y
```